# Error "is not BASE TABLE" on repairing corrupted table

Tags: mysql, heidisql

One of my tables got corrupted, so, in order to correct, I used the interface of HeidiSql. The problem is that during the process of repair, my connection to the internet was losted, and now the HeidiSQL throws me the error "is not BASE TABLE" if I try to repair.

PPS: HeidiSQL says that mine table is a View

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to get a answer more easily :)

Comment: @ValentinMichalak thanks for the tips, I'll try to make it more clear.

Answer (score 9):

Usually the problem with "`is not BASE TABLE`" is that the "table" you are trying to modify is not a table, it's a "view".

To confirm that, you can launch:

```
SHOW FULL TABLES IN dbname WHERE TABLE_TYPE LIKE 'VIEW';
```

If the table you are trying to repair appears here, bingo! it's a view.

If you are using MariaDB 10.X or above, you can try

```
REPAIR VIEW table_name;
```